# <form> and $_POST with sql in php

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, post

I have this form list:

```
<form action="">
Inlognaam: <input type="text" name="inlognaam">
</form>
```

Now i want it that if you put there text in, the text will set into the database.

```
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","phpexpr");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

$inlognaam = $_POST['inlognaam']; 


if(isset($POST['inlognaam'])){
$filename = $_POST['inlognaam'];
}
if(isset($filename)){ 
echo $filename;
}
$sql = 'INSERT INTO gebruikers (inlognaam) VALUES('.$filename.')';
mysql_query($sql);
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}   
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I got this code, but i don't know what there is wrong and what schould be changed.
Can somebody help me please? :)

Comment: *you* tell *us* what's wrong. That's how it works here.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: You're opening your database connection with `mysqli`, but using `mysql_query` to query it. You can't mix calls like this. Change any calls to `mysql_*()` to use `mysqli_*()`.

Comment: I got this errors Notice: Undefined index: inlognaam in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\index.php on line 56

Notice: Undefined variable: filename in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\index.php on line 65

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\index.php on line 67
Error: No database selected

Comment: and PLEASE improve the sql injection problem in your code, by changing the sql to $sql = 'INSERT INTO gebruikers (inlognaam) VALUES('. mysql_real_escape_string($filename).')';

Comment: sql injection means: it's very easy to drop your database/stealing your data/change your data by filling out your form in a special way.

Comment: @jamie0726 No, don't mix `mysql_*` functions with `mysqli_*` ones; use [**prepared statements**](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to prevent [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: @MarcelKorpel I totally agree that prepared statements are the way to go in general but before user2870245 does nothing at all because learning prepared statements is too much for his current level of developing expertise -> mysql_real_escape_string is better than nothing.

Comment: @jamie0726 I don't agree that prepared statements are that more difficult to learn, but if you really want, then use `mysqli_real_escape_string`, not `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel mysqli_real_escape_string: mea culpa, you're right of course - as for preparedStatements: the question sounds like the person asking is not an experienced (PHP) developer, so it is great that you gave an copy/paste example as a starting point for prepared statements. Hope he/she will use it :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are several flaws with your code:

- you don't specify a method, so your form will be sent with GET, whereas you use `$_POST` variables in your PHP code. Use

  ```
  <form action="" method="POST">
  ```
- you are mixing `mysql_*` functions and `mysqli_*` functions. Don't use the former anymore, those are deprecated. Use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) (I prefer the latter). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).
- you're performing two queries here (resulting in two INSERTs):

  ```
  mysql_query($sql);
  if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  ```

  just catch the value of the first query (and use `mysqli_query` if you want to use MySQLi).
- last but not least, due to your string concatanation of your query, you're open to SQL injection. Switch to [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) like this:

  ```
  $sql = 'INSERT INTO gebruikers (inlognaam) VALUES (?)';
  $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $filename);
  $success = $_stmt->execute();

  if ($success) {
      …
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Use the method name POST at the line `<form action="" method="post">`
    and one thing you have mistake that use `$_POST` NOT `$POST` in the line

```
if(isset($POST['inlognaam'])){
$filename = $_POST['inlognaam'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here,

When you dont specify method attributes of form tag, then default it will use GET method to post data.

So set  or use $_REQUEST to get data from html file which independant of form method.

Answer (score 0):

The form maybe like this `<form action="" method="POST">`
try it

Answer (score -1):

Can you give us an error if you're getting one? I see that you're using a MySQLI connection but you're putting everything in the database with just a MySQL query.

You need this code:

```
<form action="" method="POST">

  <?php

// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","phpexpr");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQLI: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

$inlognaam = trim($_POST['inlognaam']); 


if(isset($_POST['inlognaam']))
{
$filename = trim($_POST['inlognaam']);
}
if(isset($filename))
{ 
echo $filename;
}

$sql = 'INSERT INTO gebruikers (inlognaam) VALUES('.$con->real_escape_string($filename).')';
$con->query($sql);

if (!mysqli_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
}   
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I've used OO side of MySQLI because I'm not used to produceral side of MySQLI, apoliges for that and the bad English from my side.

I also see that you didn't declared the action in your form, you need to use POST if you wont that user can post informatie that you can send to your DB.

Comment: I have used your codes, and now i get those erros.  Notice: Undefined index: inlognaam in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\index.php on line 56

Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\index.php on line 68

Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\index.php on line 68

Comment: I've changed my first post, my bad...

Comment: You perform the same query twice, resulting in another bug.